# Difference between Entity Module and Extension Module in vTiger

Tags: php, vtiger

What is the difference between an Extension Module and an Entity Module in vTiger, and in which situation am I supposed to create either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It think it is more a wording thing. You call the module defining a new entity (to hold data records) entity module. Both types instantiate the same class Vtiger_Module.

See here:

An Entity Module Example : http://community.vtiger.com/help/vtigercrm/developers/extensions/examples/entity-module.html

An Extension Module Example : 
http://community.vtiger.com/help/vtigercrm/developers/extensions/examples/extension-module.html